# OpenCV Save Image Dramatically Increases File Size of .tif

Tags: python, opencv, tiff

I'm using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) in Python to find images within other images using the [MatchTemplate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/object_detection.html) method.  I've noticed that when I load a .tif file then re-save it, even if I have not altered the image in opencv, the file size is increasing dramatically, e.g., from 68kb to 25mb.

I wrote a very basic script to verify that this happens without any other code modifying the image.

```
import cv, sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

image = cv.LoadImage(filename)
cv.SaveImage('test.tif', image)
```

I didn't see any options for optimizing the image.  Any ideas on how I might be able to maintain the original file size within OpenCV or is this just a matter of compressing after the fact?

Comment: Well I have just the same issue but with `.png` files, I do exactly the same thing you do and from 37kB I go to 144kB.

Comment: As indicated below, I think this is really just an issue of OpenCV not preserving the original compression.  If you want compressed images, you'll have to re-compress after calling SaveImage().

Comment: Is it somehow possible to compress the image with OpenCV functionality or you mean here some 3rd party program ?

Comment: For tiffs, I used tiffcp, but I'd just google whatever format you are trying to compress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the source is compressed tif while the rewritten one is not compressed.

See https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1080 for a potential solution

Comment: Thanks - I'm guessing this is the case.  LoadImage is able to read the compressed image but doesn't retain that information so SaveImage just writes the uncompressed tiff.